# Inverse of a matrix in 2n^3 operetions in Matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I'm trying to find an algorithm in Matlab which can return the inverse of a matrix with 2n^3 arithmetic operations at most (thus not counting assignments or comparisons). I've tried with the usual Gauss elimination algorithm: since finding the inverse is not different from solving a linear system of the kind A[X1 | X2 | ... | X*n*] = [e1 | ... | e*n*] with e*i* being the *ith* identity matrix column. But this yields (2/3)n^3 + 2n^3 operations, I need 2n^3. I think I should exploit the fact that the columns have all zeros except for the *ith* element of the column. This way I should be able to reduce the current (8/3)n^3 cost to only 2n^3.

Any idea on how I can manage that?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Yes. I'll edit that.

Comment: out of curiosity: what is the reason for the 2n³ requirement?

Comment: @m.s.: my professor said it was possible to improve (8/3)n^3 to 2n^3, so I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: just a tip - this question might be better suited for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This seems like an intellectual exercise, probably better suited for another forum as pointed out by another comment. You say you want to use matlab -- are you aware that matlab has already implemented probably the fastest matrix inverse algorithm currently known, and that unless you exclusively use vector and matrix notation in matlab your code will almost certainly be slower than if you implemented it in say, c? (because Matlab is an interpreted language, so things like for loops run pretty slow)

Comment: Yes I knew that, btw I solved this so thank you all.